# Rails axlsx_rails gem. Insert new row between existing rows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spreadsheet, axlsx

I am generating `.xlsx` files using [`axlsx_rails`](https://github.com/straydogstudio/axlsx_rails) gem based on [`axlsx`](https://github.com/randym/axlsx). I am receiving rows as array and drawing them like this:

```
# Workbook, sheet and styles creations left... 
data["config"].each do |item|
    sheet.add_row item.each_with_index.map{|row, index| row["value"]}, :style => row_style       
end
```

Then I need to insert a new row between for example 2nd and 3rd rows. I wonder how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems there ought to be a better way to do this, but you can add a row, delete it, and insert it elsewhere:

```
sheet.add_row %w{this row is inserted}
sheet.rows.insert 2, sheet.rows.delete_at(sheet.rows.length-1)
```

`sheet.rows.insert` requires an `Axlsx::Row` object. You *can* create one separately, but the initializer requires a worksheet parameter, and it adds the row to the worksheet implicitly:

```
new_row = Axlsx::Row.new sheet, %w{this row is inserted}
sheet.rows.last # => returns new_row
# so we still have to do the same thing
sheet.rows.insert 2, sheet.rows.delete_at(sheet.rows.length-1)
```

You may as well use the first. YMMV with complicated worksheets.

[More docs here](https://www.omniref.com/ruby/gems/axlsx/2.0.1/classes/Axlsx::Row#).

Comment: I believe the `delete` calls should be `delete_at` since an index is being passed.

Comment: can confirm, it needs to be `delete_at` instead of `delete`

Comment: Changed to delete_at

Answer (score 1):

`sheet.rows.insert [index]`, `sheet.rows.delete(sheet.rows.last)` `#index` is the row that you want to insert ont